Serilog MinimumLevel Override is not working
{
"Logging":{
  "LogLevel":{
    "Default": "Warning",
    "System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SomeClassLibraryName": "Error"
   }
  }
}

If I add the above code in my app settings then the logs for above-provided namespace only get written for the error and it works.
But when I try to achieve the same thing using the logging configuration for Serilog in .NET 6 WEB API it does not work. This is the method of which I am calling for setting the log configuration :
public static void LoggingConfiguration()
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SomeClassLibraryName", LogEventLevel.Error)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .MinimumLevel.Override(SomeClassLibraryName, LogEventLevel.Information)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Async(c => c.File("Logs/Log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
        .WriteTo.Async(c => c.Console())
        .CreateLogger();
}

I have tested this code for Microsoft and by changing the minimum level from information to warning and error, it works for them but is not working for a specific case.
I have explored the following options so far but did not find any satisfactory results.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#source-contexts
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1390
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/177

And where do you call this LoggingConfiguration? I would expect it requires registration via options or smth. Like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#default-log-level

The method is being called in the Program.cs and its working fine, I hv tested some scenerios

And what would be the scenarios in which it does not work?

"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SomeClassLibraryName": "Error", at the same time if I put this in the app settings it works perfectly, but due to constraint I want to control it via my custom method not app settings

@Pawel your idea worked, that config is for Serilog. But the thing I am trying comes in Asp.Net.Core Logging. Following code in the Program.cs worked, builder.Logging.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ClassLibraryName", LogLevel.None);

Add it as an answer @Pawel

You should rely on built-in registration like here.
Try moving the registration to builder like so:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);

or
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Logging.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ClassLibraryName", LogLevel.None);


Serilog does not use the default Logging section, by default it uses Serilog one (with MinimumLevel for log level configs, see for example How to prevent logging all of my Entity Framework SQL queries? or the docs), it is used by the build-in logger, so either register Serilog (from the Serilog.AspNetCore docs):
LoggingConfiguration(); // call your Serilog setup
// install the Serilog.AspNetCore package
builder.Services.AddSerilog();

or use the build-in logger APIs (docs):
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);
builder.Logging.AddFilter("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.ClassLibraryName", LogLevel.None);

Though personally I would recommend to stick with the config approach as far more flexible one.
